# USB for Linux BootUSB drive

Tags: usb, linux

I'm looking for a cheap USB drive for my installation by [BootUSB](https://wiki.debian.org/BootUsb). I want use it **only** for this job, and I usually install Linux distros.

I have an old 2GB drive but seems slow when it installs. What drive do you suggest? I don't want pay a lot, maximum of €15, and the storage  should  be 8/16GB (if I use it as virtual CD).

Comment: In this case you can choose "anything". Tell us more about your price range and storage capacity.

Comment: Any USB drive that follows the USB mass storage standard (ie. almost every drive ever made) and is large enough meets your needs.

Comment: I have asked this because I have an old 2GB USB drive, but I think that it goes slow when I install the distros. I want 8Gb (max 16 Gb) drive.

Comment: @linofex, please edit your question and put this information & price range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sandisk Extreme is a good mix of budget and speed.  smaller size is better performance on these devices [Sandisk Extreme](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DZPUOU8)

[USB Benchmark Links Like This](http://usb.userbenchmark.com/) are fairly reliable sources for your consumer research purposes

Comment: The sale is amazing  but I live in Italy and on amazon.it the drive costs  more, out  of my budget.

Comment: if you can get your hands on sandisk extreme or ultra you should be in the right ballpark

Comment: sorry, I don't  understand

Comment: Ha, sorry, ballpark reference meaning: if you can find Sandisk Extreme or Ultra drives locally, you should be able to get good price / performance.